# Unlimited number of arguments for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, arguments

I would like to run queries for SQL Server that have variable and potentially unlimited number of parameters, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees 
WHERE 
      employee_dob < @dob1 
      AND employee_dob >= @dob2 
      AND (employee_id = @param1 
           OR employee_id = @param2 ...
           ...
           OR employee_id = @paramN)
```

N can vary from 1 to large number, say 1000.

What would be an optimal way for that?

Comment: Table-valued parameter ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep, seems like that's it, thank you